# What conclusion could be drawn about the maps from their compostie?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to C$. Then

1. If $g \circ f$ is injective, then I know that $f$ is injective, but what can we say about the injectivity of $g$?
2. If $g \circ f$ is surjective, then I know that $g$ is surjective, but what can we say about the surjectivity of $f$?

Comment: 1. $g$  can be either injective, surjective or neither. 2.$f$ can be either injective or surjective or neither.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example,

(1)  Let $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{4,5\}$ and $C=\{7\}$.

$f(1)=4$ and $g(4)=g(5)=7$. Clearly $g\circ f$ is injective and $g$ is not injective.

(2) Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{4,5,6\}$ and $C=\{7\}$.

$f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=4$ and $g(4)=g(5)=g(6)=7$. Clearly $g\circ f$ is surjective, however $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

No thing we can say about injectivity of $g$ except that it is injective  on $f(A)$.

For next question also it means that $g$ maps $f(A)$ to entire $C$,no thing more.